# AM Demodulation in Tikz, how to implement a lowpass function

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: AM Demodulation]

I want to draw the following picture in tikz. Number 1 is simple its a sin(X)*sin(Y) and Number 2 is just abs(sin(X)*sin(Y)). Number 4 is obviously easy too. A similar example could be found here:

https://github.com/PetarV-/TikZ/tree/master/Amplitude%20modulation

However, has somebody a clue how to draw Number 3? It's basically a lowpassfiltering of the signal Number 2. Has tikz this capability? I know somebody might say, just plot it in Matlab. But it must be done in LaTeX! Of course, I can do it somehow manually in Tikz with splines etc. But it would be nice if we could get the real system's behaviour in this picture.

Comment: What are you asking for exactly? Are you looking for an analytical formula for the envelope? Are you asking for numerical code that can generate the envelope? If you know how to use Matlab to get the envelope, how about exporting the numerical data from Matlab and importing them into LaTeX, plotting it in `tikz`?

Comment: @MatthiasArras yeah I thought about this option. But actually I wonder if there is also a Tikz only solution.

Comment: Nothing builtin to TikZ (or `pgfplots`), as far as I know.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at the documentation of the pstricks package `pst-am` which has some examples of your 3rd curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by using Octave/Matlab and the tool matlab2tikz https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz